# Embedding RSS and Twitter onto Static FBML?

Tags: facebook, rss, twitter, fbml, fbjs

I've been asked to build a facebook fan page, that displays the latest RSS from a blog and the latest tweets from an user.

Something just like this:
http://www.facebook.com/ibmargentina?v=app_223277347226&ref=ts

I already know the basics for working with FBML, but I can't figure how can I display external data...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=129641

Here is another how to: http://www.howtoforge.com/rss_facebook_app_php_p3

Check out the discussions, everything you want to know is there.
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?sid=59c8a2bba844922b5153efc9b9eba237&id=4949752878&ref=s

Comment: Wow! There are tons of topics and most of them are in russian. Do you at least if embedding RSS feed into FBML is possible?? Thanks!

Comment: I will edit my post with a discussion abou0t this very topic, the short answer is yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has put up a new guide for apps and pages at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas that is fairly helpful.

One thing that was a bit elusive to me at first was that you have one page that serves the canvas and then you have a second page (they recommend a subdirectory /tab) that serves the page content. So you can have a working app and canvas page and still not have it show up as a tab when you add the app to your "page".

(I know this is an old question, but I found it so I figure others might too)